# Android: any way to check if "menu" button will exist when full-screen?

Tags: android

My app has code to go full-screen where sensible to do so -- it's sensible on most Android 1 and 2 devices, but under Android 3 for example going full-screen loses the app menu button, and at the moment I don't implement my own menu button so users can't (or at least can't easily) get to the app's menu.

At the moment I test for Android version < 3, and go full-screen if that's the case, but I have users with Android 2 tablets (Viewsonic view pad 10s for example) where this isn't sensible (the Viewsonic user tells me she has to hold down the back button to get app's menu to appear).

Is there a better way of testing whether going full-screen will lose the menu button? Or going full screen only if it's sensible to do so?

Thanks for any help you can give. Let me know if you need more info or if the above isn't clear.

Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a better way of testing whether going full-screen will lose the menu button?

No. The Viewsonic device in question does not qualify for the Android Market, AFAIK, and all bets are off in terms of compatibility for devices that fail to meet the requirements for the Market.

Comment: Thanks -- I may just add a preference visible only under Android 1 and 2 which allows people to switch off the full-screen behaviour (provided they can find some way to get to the Settings menu :-) if I can't think of anything better. I'll leave the question open for a while yet in case anyone else has any input, then mark it as answered.